# Grub 2 removed, Windows can't boot

Tags: windows, linux, boot, grub

In all my stupidity I used Windows to reformat my Ubuntu partition and now I can't boot anything.  What's the best way to recover my netbook? I'm only able to use a 256 MB flash drive.

Comment: This problem has been encouraged by many people! I would also like to know the best possible way to recover!

Comment: Surprisingly, I can't find a duplicate for this question on this site. It is indeed something likely to happen more and more often, with the success of linux distributions like Ubuntu growing each year. It would be nice to have a very clear and detailed answer for this situation.

Comment: If it'd be that much of a success , people wouldn't delete it. :PPPP

Answer (score 4):

**Vista** / **Windows 7**:
Get the Windows 7 DVD or get a bigger pendrive and copy the DVD there. At any rate, go to recovery console, and use:
`BootRec.exe /FixMbr`
`BootRec.exe /FixBoot`

This always does the job.
[Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) about this (if you don't believe me (the usual hollywood "its gonna eat mah PC!!!11"))..

---

**Windows XP**:
Get the recovery console. You can do that in the installer, about the very first steps (watch the bottom part for the message "For recovery console".. (or maybe its amongst the text at center, anyway, you can see it clearly.)

There:
`Fixboot`
`Fixmbr`

Reboot, have phun.
XP [article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6031733.html) before your PC blows up.

Forgot to mention: This works on all kind of problems. Like Grub 1.97 or something like that.